Display Number of Days in the current Month
I have an assignment for my C++ class that is mostly complete. However, I am unsure as to how I am supposed to make the program display the days of the current month. I'm able to make it work with user input, but I can't finish it off the way I'm asked to in the assignment.
{
    time_t epSeconds;

        tm *pCalendarTime = nullptr;

        string monthnames[] = {"January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"};

        epSeconds = time (NULL);

        pCalendarTime = localtime(&epSeconds);


    cout << "This is " << monthnames[pCalendarTime->tm_mon] << "," << 1900 + pCalendarTime->tm_year << endl;

}

I tried to change the names to each month so it includes the number of days for the month, but I run into the issue of February. I tried connecting the days to the month but I just keep getting today's date. I know it's something silly that I'm just not seeing.

The code you've shown does not match the problem you describe. February has a well-defined calculation to determine whether it has 28 or 29 days depending on the year.

I know it has that, but I'm asking about how to display that information with cout<<. When I ran the code, it gave me the date, and not how many days there are. I'm trying to find out how to display the number of days for the month using the bit of code I showed. Would it help if I posted the entire code so you can see more of what I'm trying to do?

You have to determine the number of days yourself. That information is not returned in struct tm. Use an array to represent the number of days for each month.

"Current month" as defined by UTC, or as defined by some local time zone?  Perhaps the computer's locally set time zone?  When I ask the question both ways on my computer I'm currently getting two different answers (30 and 31).

Did you try using std::chrono Date-time utilities? Check the calendar section here: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono

adding this to your code snippet
(you can also use chrono library)
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include <string> 

using namespace std;

// This function will get the number of days in a month
int days_in_month(int month, int year) {
    // This array contains the number of days in each month
    int days[] = { 31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31 };

    // Leap year checking
    if (month == 2 && ((year % 4 == 0 && year % 100 != 0) || (year % 400 == 0))) {
        return 29;
    }

    return days[month - 1];
}

int main() {
    time_t epSeconds;
    tm *pCalendarTime = nullptr;
    string monthnames[] = {"January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"};

    epSeconds = time(NULL);
    pCalendarTime = localtime(&epSeconds);

    int month = pCalendarTime->tm_mon + 1;
    int year = 1900 + pCalendarTime->tm_year;
    int days = days_in_month(month, year);

    cout << "This is " << monthnames[pCalendarTime->tm_mon] << ", " << year << endl;
    cout << "The number of days in the current month is: " << days << endl;

    return 0;
}


I keep getting the error that "month is not declared" when trying out this code. Is there something I'm missing?

@SolidSnake212 Maybe a typo or incorrect compilation 'int month' is declared correctly in the code above double check if you misspelled it or if there are any environmental issues also here is the output :
This is July, 2024
The number of days in the current month is: 31

You can use Calendar utilities from std::chrono for this:
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>
#include <array>
#include <format>

int main()
{
    const auto now = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
    const auto ymd = std::chrono::year_month_day{
        std::chrono::floor<std::chrono::days>(now) // overload (4)
    };
    auto month_last_day_ymd = ymd.year() / ymd.month() / std::chrono::last;
    std::cout << "This is " << std::format("{:%B, %Y}", ymd) << '\n';
    std::cout << "The number of days in the current month is: " << month_last_day_ymd.day() << '\n';
}


Upvoted for the use of chrono.  Here's an easier way to print out the month and year that removes the need for the array: std::cout << "This is " << std::format("{:%B, %Y}", ymd);.  And here's a simpler way to construct month_last_day_ymd: auto month_last_day_ymd = ymd.year() / ymd.month() / std::chrono::last;.

Thanks for the suggestions @HowardHinnant, edited my answer :-)
